# Orchard CMS 1.3 Theme Custom Zone Application

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, themes, orchardcms

I'm creating a new theme in Orchard v1.3. Coming from 1.2 creating custom zones were just adding text in the Theme.txt in the theme folder.

Now in v1.3 there's a Zone folder and the Theme.txt doesn't have the Zones section anymore. So far I haven't found guides on how to use the new Zones folder. I'm guessing it's where you can add .cshtml to be appended to the Layout.cshtml.

Am I right with my assumption or are there existing guides for the new Theming convention in Orchard V1.3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can ignore those zones folders. Nothing changed. Nothing. You are fine. Nothing to see here.